# double comparing using if from JLabel

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, double, jlabel

i have been trying to figure this out i have an array of JLabels and an array of doubles, and when i use an if statement it will not throw when the values are the same,

```
 public static int notobtn(int in ) {
 int returnVal = 0;
 int no = 0;
 for (no = 0; no < 26; no++) {
     System.out.println("----------------------");
     System.out.println("ScrambleAmt = " + Gui.ScrambleAmt[ in ]);
     System.out.println("number = " + Double.valueOf(Gui.lbls[no].getText().replaceAll("[^\\w]", "")));
     System.out.println("----------------------");
     if (Gui.ScrambleAmt[ in ] == Double.valueOf(Gui.lbls[no].getText().replaceAll("[^\\w]", ""))) {
         returnVal = no;
         System.out.println("WINNER");
     }
 }
 return returnVal;
```

}

The  Gui.lbls[] are as follows (a $ sign is placed in front of them thats why i have the replace all)

```
    Double[] labelamt = {
    0.50, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 100.0, 150.0,
    200.0, 250.0, 500.0, 750.0, 1000.0, 2000.0, 3000.0, 4000.0, 5000.0, 10000.0,
    15000.0, 20000.0, 30000.0, 50000.0, 75000.0, 100000.0, 200000.0
};
```

The scrambleAmt[] is also a double array with exactly the same number only shuffled everytime the program runs, the console is printing out all the numbers, but when it gets to the number where theyre equal it doesnt print "Winner" and the returnVal stays set to 0.

if anyone could please help me out i think it has something todo with the parsing of the JLabel value,but i would be very greatful :D thanks a lot in advance

piemansam5

Comment: I don't think your parsing method of the double values in labels is correct. Try a different regex.

Comment: it removes the $ sign fine and when i print the values it is just digits and a decimal point, so im pretty sure it is all good that one but either way could i grab some of the regexes please i would appreciate it a lot

Comment: I tried with [^0-9.,] and it worked. It can be improved.

Comment: im still having trouble, the if statement still wont throw :/
thats using the new regex

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
double.valueOf()
```

to

```
double.parseDouble()
```